# Querying data from SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, mono, sql-server-2012

I’m trying to add SQL Server support to the Mono (on Linux, not Android if it matters) version of one of our products.

I have a codebase that works fine on Windows, but under Mono, it’s not behaving.  We’re using SQL Authentication, not NT.

I am able to get back a list of table names, so I know it’s “talking” to the database, but when I attempt to query rows from a table I get this:

> > [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Exception: Unknown packet type 129
> >       at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetPhysicalPacketHeader () [0x00000] in :0
> >       at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetPhysicalPacket () [0x00000] in :0
> >       at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.Peek () [0x00000] in :0
> >       at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.NextResult () [0x00000] in :0
> >       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar () [0x00000] in :0
> >       at OpenNETCF.ORM.SQLStoreBase`1[OpenNETCF.ORM.SqlEntityInfo].ExecuteScalar (System.String sql) [0x00000] in :0
> >       at OpenNETCF.ORM.SqlServerDataStore.get_ServerVersion () [0x00000] in :0
> >       at OpenNETCF.ORM.SqlServerDataStore.Fetch (System.String entityName, Int32 fetchCount, Int32 firstRowOffset, System.String sortField, FieldSearchOrder sortOrder, OpenNETCF.ORM.FilterCondition filter, Boolean fillReferences) [0x00000] in :0
> >       at SolutionFamily.Storage.DataEntityProvider.GetEntityInstances (System.String entityName, Int32 skipNumber, Int32 retrieveNumber) [0x00000] in :0
> >     {more call stack omitted}

So it looks like the TDS version in Mono is old, maybe?  [Packet type 129 looks like it’s a “result” packet from version 7.0 on](http://www.freetds.org/tds.html#t129), so it's not something new as far as I can tell.  It’s been in use since SQL Server 7, which itself is pretty far from “recent”.

So my questions, I guess, are:

- Is connecting to a SQL Server 2012 database from a Mono app a supported scenario?
- Has anyone had any luck connecting to a “modern” version of SQL Server?
- Is there a newer version of TDS on the System.Data.* stuff available that adds support?
- Any thoughts on how to proceed (other than debugging Mono and attempting to implement this stuff myself)?

Comment: Did you ever bring this to a conclusion? Is Sql Server 2012 supported by Mono?

Comment: My conclusion is outlined in the accepted answer below - don't try to call `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY`.  It may have changed since that time, but I just worked the code around it and never had to go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the offending SQL statement in my code is this:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')
```

I tried chaning the call from an `ExecuteScalar()` to an `ExecuteReader()` and then reading the first column of the first row, but that, too, explodes.  There's something about that statement (or more likely what SQL Server is returning as a result from it) that TDS doesn't like.

Fortunately we only use the resulting version for determining what types of queries to run (we have faster queries for newer servers that support them) and just reverting to "old" still appears to allow all the rest of the code to run, so I modified the caller to look like this:

```
public Version ServerVersion 
{
    get
    {
        // Mono doesn't like selecting SERVERPROPERTY, at least not from SQL 2012
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
        {
            return new Version(1, 0);
        }

        if (m_version == null)
        {
            var v = this.ExecuteScalar("SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')");
            m_version = new Version(v.ToString());
        }

        return m_version;
    }
}
```

Obviously the version number here isn't specifically correct, but it works for my ORM, which then selects the "older" query styles and everything proceeds as usual.  It still needs more testing for any other failures, but so far creating tables and inserting data on a SQL Server 2012 machine using the Mono.SqlClient seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right page here but have you consulted [this](http://www.mono-project.com/SQLClient)?

Regardless of the DTS problem. Even if you manage to fix that, if SQL Server 2012 is really not supported I think you would have many more problems along the way.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that page.  Unfortunately many Mono docs pages are out of date, there's no "valid as of" date on them to know how old they are, and even this one contradicts itself in different places.